# Acessar nó filho no Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Eu tenho 2 usuários. O usuário doze e o usuário treze.

Cada usuário, criou um projeto, como podem ver na imagem.

Como faço para que o usuário doze só acesse os projetos que ele criou, e o treze somente os projetos que ele criou?

Nas imagens vocês podem ver como está minha estrutura no Firebase, como estou chamando o DatabaseReference e meu método de "seleção" dos dados"[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não adicione imagens do seu código, sempre copie e cole o **texto**

Answer (score 0):

É preciso configurar as regras de negócio:

```
{
  "projeto": { //Acessa o nó onde será feita a validação
    "$chave": { //$chave representa, nesse caso, os ids criados pelo próprio Firebase ao adicionar itens
      //Se houver um usuário autenticado pelo serviço de Auth e o id desse usuário for igual ao id salvo
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid === data.child('idUsuario').val()"
      //Se houver um usuário autenticado pelo serviço de Auth e, ou se já existe esse nó (se for uma operação de alteração) e o id do usuário autenticado for igual o id salvo, ou se não existir o dado (operação de criação) e o id do usuário autenticado for igual o id salvo
      ".write": "auth != null && (data.exists() && auth.uid === data.child('idUsuario').val() || !data.exists() && auth.uid === newData.child('idUsuario').val())"
    }
  }
}
```

Além de configurar as regras de acesso para leitura (`.read`) e gravação (`.write`) é importante configurar as regras de validação, assim só é gravado dados que estejam corretamente formatado

De uma olhada na [documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) para mais informações

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tudo bem!?

Toda vez que você cria um usuário, ele não gera um id (esses nós abaixo de projetos)? salve esse id ou recupere ele:

para recuperar esse id vc pode fazer o seguinte:

Declare as seguintes variáveis:

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String mID;
```

No seu onCreate atribua os valores:

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mID = mAuth.getUid();
```

Agora no seu recuperaProjetos, vc vai passar o caminho + child("projeto") + o id do usuário logado, ficará assim:

```
DataSnapshot perfil = dataSnapshot.child("projeto").child(mID);
```

Agora você terá um Snapshot apenas do usuário em questão.